# Table with INNER JOIN, how to update

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two tables for Categories and Subcategories.
Categories has `(categorie_id and categories_name)` columns;
SubCategories has `(subCategorie_id, subCategorie_display, categorie_id, subCategory_name)` columns.
I did a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query to obtain all the records in Subcategories, and match the ones that have the same `categorie_id`. Here is my code:

```
("SELECT subCategorie_id, subCategorie_name, subCategorie_display, categories.categorie_name, subCategories.categorie_id 
  FROM subCategories 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN categories ON categories.categorie_id = subCategories.categorie_id");
```

Now i have a form in which the content is displayed. I wan't to be able to edit that form, and update the table with the updated content. This is my query:

```
("UPDATE subCategories 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN categories 
  ON categories.categorie_id = subCategories.categorie_id
  SET subCategorie_display='$display', subCategories.categorie_id='$catID',subCategorie_name='$name' 
  WHERE subCategorie_id='$id'")
```

What i get from this query is a new row with the correct content, but the one i wanted to edit, stays like it was.

Here is my HTML:

```
<select id="choosecat" name="choosecat" required>
     <?php foreach($categoriesAll as $categorie) { 
         if($subcat->categorie_id == $categorie->categorie_id) { ?>
            <option selected value="<?php echo $categorie->categorie_id; ?>"><?php echo $categorie->categorie_name; ?></option>
         <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $categorie->categorie_id; ?>"><?php echo $categorie->categorie_name; ?></option>
      <?php } }?> 
</select>
```

How can i fix this?
Already searched other answers but none worked.

Comment: Why not simple updates without join?

Comment: In the beggining i was trying this   ```("UPDATE subCategories 
                                            SET subCategorie_display='$display',
                                                  categorie_id='$catID',
                                                  subCategorie_name='$name' 
                                            WHERE 
                                                  subCategorie_id='$id'");```

Comment: What's the issue with that approach?

Comment: same. I get a new row with correct content, and the one i wanted remains the same

Comment: Did you debug and check if the query is being executed at all or not? It might happen that instead of update it is executing Insert query from other code path. Did you check what value you are getting in `$id`?

Comment: Yeah, your second post is the way to do it, but I wouldn't be updating columns data when you know good and well that data won't change, in other words... unless you assigning the subCategorie_id to a new categorie_id, you should remove categorie_id='$catID', from your SET statement...

Comment: @StephanieTemple yes, the point of this query and form is to be able to change the content for the subcategory. For example, I have a subcategory that belongs to Cats. But now i wan't to change it to dogs. That's why i have the select, to be able to change from the existing categories

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, i debbuged. I get the correct ID. I have this code calling the query: ```if(isset($_POST["subrubrique-display"])) {
  $id = $_GET["editsubcatID"];
        $display = $db->escape($_POST["subrubrique-display"]);
        $catID = $db->escape($_POST["choosecat"]);
  $name = $db->escape($_POST["subrubrique"]);
  $adverts->editSubCategorie($id, $display, $catID, $name);
  header('location: categories.php');
 }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i found the bug.
The problem was in my form action, the link was calling a wrong id.